# How to unarchive unknown objects?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, nskeyedunarchiver

I created two Apps for iPad based on 2 object classes (`classA` and `classB`).

I serialized `classA` in a file with `NSKeyedArchiver` (then attached to an email).
I want to unarchive the `classA` object in the other app that uses `classB`, without including all the headers of the other application.

**The issue**:
When I load the object from the iPad file system (from the mail attachment) using NSKeyedUnarchiver, the function returns an error ("class not recognised").

**What I have tried:**
None of these bullets work for me....
a) to check the class type (as string) and cast the objectA.
b) to include the .h definition of the objectA in the other app.

**Question:**
Is there a way to unarchive an object into a generic ID object?
Then set the parameters calling for example:

```
[genericObjectA setName:@"new name"];
[genericObjectA execute];
```

Given that I know the name of the functions and the name of the parameters to set?

Comment: No need for the tags in the title ;-)

Comment: Can you post the functions you use to archive and unarchive objects?

Answer (score 0):

Using KVO, you can set the value:

```
[genericObjectA setValue:@"new name" forKey:@"name"];
```

Then to call a method, use it's selector:

```
SEL newSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"execute");
if ([genericObjectA respondsToSelector:newSelector])
    [genericObjectA performSelector:@selector(newSelector)];
```

Comment: the problem is: the first time I load the object from the file with NSKeyedUnarchiver, the functions returns an error "object class not recognized"....

Comment: Did you implement the `NSCoding` protocol to your object? http://sam.roon.io/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding

Comment: yes, both have the protocol implemented. They work properly within each app...they just don't work when i try to load an object that is not described in the solution...